# How can I get the number of bytes availables with Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to use [this method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.IO.InputStream.Available()/) in order to get an estimated number of bytes that can be read in a JsonFile from the Asset.

For that I wrote this code:

```
  string filename;
  Stream  mf =  Context.Assets.Open(filename);
```

The problem is that I cannot have mf as an InputStream because Context.Assets.Open(filename); gives a System.IO.Stream.

And I need to define mf as an InputStream in order to be able to have the size such as:

```
int size= mf.Available();
```

I tried also:

```
InputStream  mf = AssetManager.Open(filename);
```

But I have the error of "
An object reference is required for the property , method, or the non-static field  "AssetManager.Open""

How can I get over this conflict?

Comment: Why do you want it? `Available()` is very unreliable. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.IO.InputStream.Available()/ "Note that this method provides such a weak guarantee that it is not very useful in practice."

Comment: I know but I need that estimation.

Comment: What are you trying to use `Available` for? This is not the size of the asset, but the number of bytes available in the next non-blocking call.

Comment: Interesting. In Java `AssetManager.open()` returns InputStream. May be you can cast `Context.Assets.Open(filename)` to InputStream?

Comment: I tried that already but il doesn't work..

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract Java class, just use an asset file descriptor, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the actual Asset file size, there are two things you need to do:

**1st:** Set the file NOT to be compressed

Example, change extension to something unique, i.e. `.utxt`

Set those file extensions not to be compressed in your app package:

[image]

**2nd:** Use an asset file descriptor:

```
var fileFD = Assets.OpenFd("json.utxt");
Log.Debug("JSON", fileFD.Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/), you can try something like this:

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

where this is the context.

The .NET [Stream](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.IO.Stream/) class doesn't have a method similar to the the java [available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) method. In the matter of fact, the java documentation states thatL

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the
>   total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never
>   correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer
>   intended to hold all data in this stream.

and

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.
>
> This method should be overridden by subclasses.

in summary, the available method is intended to be implemented by the sub classes and it's not always guaranteed to return the available length so it's not advised to use it in allocating buffers as the docs state.

So you can check the Stream.Length property and read the whole stream or allocate a buffer with a size less than the stream's length.

Comment: `Open()` isn't static method. You need to get AssetManager object first.

Comment: Can you develop your answer ?

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't answer my question .. My goal is to be able to use the method available not Length

Comment: Please check the updated answer for more clarification

Comment: Thank your for the effort.. I am trying your suggestion but I get an exception with Length:

System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Comment: I believe that the Length property is not implemented in Xamarin Stream base class, it may be implemented in sub classes such as FileStream or MemoryStream, please check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117916/discussion-between-fao-and-mina-samy).